# tornadoFx runAsync {} ui {} not working

Tags: tornadofx

What I need is to call same controller method from two different views. 
For example I need to call

```
controller.getProducts()
```

from ProductView.class as well as from StockView.class
I call this `controller.getProducts()` to populate data inside a tableView and comboBox using

```
runAsync{
    controller.getProducts()
}ui{
    items = it
}
```

But this works only for one time. Whichever view I visit first this works. But for the second view this does not work.
I would like to mention , this bellow code works .

```
    runAsync{
val it = controller.getProducts()
runLater{
items =it
}
```

Please solve my puzzle

Comment: Please post a complete class that showcases the issue, there must be something else going on here.

Comment: Is your controller caching the results of `getProducts()`?

Comment: i am writing any code for caching the result. getProducts() called each time. But the ui {.........} is invoked for the first time only.